# Как получить ответ от bluetooth dialog?

Tags: java, android

**Проблема такая**: при региcтрирации receiver блютуза и он мне выдает callback. Но проблема в том, что до регистрации проходит получение разрешения на включение блютуз.

Если юзер нажимает ДА то все ок - receiver регистрируется и срабатывают колбэки receiver-a. А если он нажал НЕТ - я никакого ивента не получаю.

**Вопрос**: Как получить ответ разрешения? Дал ли юзер соглашение или нет? Разрешение просится самой системой. Я отдельно не пишу для пермишина что либо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Результат выдачи разрешений доступен в коллбэке в `Activity` или `Fragment` в зависимости от того, где именно вы вызывали `requestPermissions`

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
   if (requestCode == ANY_REQUEST_CODE) {
      if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         // Разрешение выдано
      } else {
         // Разрешение не выдано
      }
   }
}
```

P.S. Советую почитать по этому поводу [официальную документацию](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Comment: а если это диалоговое окно вызывается само при регистрации receiver   я не давал запрос на регистрацию)

Comment: по какому резуль коду отследить

Comment: @elik, по такому же, с каким вы это разрешение запрашиваете при вызове `requestPermissions`. Дополнил ответ ссылкой на официальную документацию

Comment: вот что я вызываю) Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        getContext().startActivity(enableBTIntent);

Comment: @elik, вы должны самостоятельно проверять наличие нужных разрешений, а в случае их отсутствия - запрашивать

Comment: нет нашел ответ